# finding a wiki and forum that share the same users

Tags: php, wiki, forums

Hello I'm hoping to find a PHP/MySql based Wiki and Forum software that can share the same users.

Can anyone suggest any products that work well together?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Hi Topener, I haven't used LDAP before. But you're suggesting that I should look for two products that use that technology? I'm hoping that a user will be able to log into either system with the same user and password. Plus integration of permissions. Will LDAP help?

Comment: Yes! Ldap is your solution for that!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at LDAP.

http://www.MediaWiki.org has LDAP support: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication

I don't know which forum uses LDAP, but they are there. Possible the big phpbb or simplemachines. Not sure about that one.